# How to communicate between window and iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have following two input buttons on the parent `window`

```
<input type="button" value="bisque Theme" id="btn-bisque" />
<input type="button" value="violet theme" id="btn-violet" />
```

And in the `frame` I want to access the ids of the buttons so I can apply following logic in my `frame`

```
$('#btn-bisque').click(function () {
    $('#CustomStyle').css('color','red');
});
$('#btn-violet').click(function () {
    $('#CustomStyle').css('color','blue');
});
```

Is this communication between parent and frame document possible? If yes, how?

Comment: `$("iframe").find("#id").click()`

Comment: where would I write this code? In frame or parent?

Comment: Using `$("iframe").find("#id")`, you can select element in iframe from out of it.